# Get User Information from Identity Server 4 Authentication Server on Resource Server during request

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I am at a loss on how to retrieve the current user info (using current access token) from my resource server after authentication on my identity server application. Is there a way to do that in the middleware or in the controllers?

Comment: your identity server needs to create a JWT with a secret you provide. as long as long as your web application shares the same secret, you shouldn't have an issue.

Comment: The `access_token` is for use by your API, not Identity Server.  Use the `id_token` for accessing Identity Server endpoints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using [IdentityModel](https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel2). Like so:

```
var discoveryClient = new DiscoveryClient("https://youridp.com");
var doc = await discoveryClient.GetAsync();

var userInfoClient = new UserInfoClient(doc.UserInfoEndpoint, token);

var response = await userInfoClient.GetAsync();
var claims = response.Claims;
```

Comment: Where does the `token` variable come from?

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to save them in your access-token because that access-token will be used to authorize a user within a resource-api.

When now accessing an endpoint from your resource-api, you can access these claims.

```
var userName = this.HttpContext.User.Identity.Claims.First(claim => claim.Type == JwtClaimTypes.Preferred_UserName).Value; // gets the username when set

var userId = this.HttpContext.User.Identity.Claims.First(claim => claim.Type == JwtClaimTypes.Subject).Value; // gets the users id when set
```

You can also extract the access-token from the request

```
var token = this.HttpContext.Request.Headers['Authorization'].Replace("Bearer ", "");
```

Then use the discover client and request the oauth profile via `/connect/userinfo`. That only works if you have [implemented it](https://identitymodel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/client/userinfo.html).